# Sqlite data don't show after close recent apps

Tags: android, sqlite

Every time I stop the application, the data in the database is not displayed and the database is created from the first.
I do not know exactly where the problem is
Need more and accurate guidance
Now the information is stored and displayed, but when the application is closed from recent apps, the database is rebuilt.

```
public SevenLearnDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + POST_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL_PAGE + " TEXT, " +
                COL_PAGE2 + " TEXT, " +
                COL_NIAT + " TEXT, " +
                COL_DATE + " TEXT);");

        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + "create database");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


public boolean addPost(Post post) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_ID, post.getId());
    cv.put(COL_PAGE, post.getPage());
    cv.put(COL_PAGE2, post.getPage2());
    cv.put(COL_NIAT, post.getNiat());
    cv.put(COL_DATE, post.getDate());

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long isInserted = sqLiteDatabase.insert(POST_TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

    Log.i(TAG, "addPost: " + isInserted + "-" + post.getDate());

    if (isInserted > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void addPosts(List<Post> posts) {
    for (int i = 0; i < posts.size(); i++) {
            addPost(posts.get(i));
    }
}

public List<Post> getPosts() {
    List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + POST_TABLE_NAME, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Post post = new Post();
            post.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            post.setPage(cursor.getString(1));
            post.setPage2(cursor.getString(2));
            post.setNiat(cursor.getString(3));
            post.setDate(cursor.getString(4));
            posts.add(post);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    System.out.println("rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr" + cursor.getCount());
    return posts;
}
```

Comment: please show us DATABASE_NAME and DATABASE_VERSION too.

Comment: public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android.android.eshgh";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

Comment: Thanks checking it now

Comment: How does "database is rebuilt" manifest itself in your app? Nothing terribly wrong with the code you posted. How are you storing and displaying entries in your database?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code will result in the `getPosts` method failing due to the Cursor being closed when `cursor.getCount()` is invoked.

```
cursor.close();
sqLiteDatabase.close();
System.out.println("rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr" + cursor.getCount());
return posts;
```

Try changing this to :-

```
System.out.println("rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr" + cursor.getCount()); //<<<< MOVED BEFORE CURSOR CLOSE
cursor.close();
sqLiteDatabase.close();
return posts;
```